# nvidia framerate limiter mode

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card

There's this program
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Orbmu2k/nvidiaprofileinspector/build/artifacts
nvidia profile inspector, that allows you to change the registry entries of your nvidia drivers for different games/programs. One setting in particular intrigues me, its called "Frame Rate Limiter Mode"

Basically, when one sets it to either

"0.00000004 PS_FRAMERATE_LIMITER_2_CONTROL_DELAY_FLIP_BY_FLIPMETERING"

or

"0x00000010 PS_FRAMERATE_LIMITER_2_CONTROL_ALLOW_ALL_MAXWELL"

I get substantially less input lag in any game I set this for, without changing anything else. Does anyone have an idea why? This setting is unavaliable in the normal control panel so I assume its hidden for a reason. I've had this set across multiple games now and have yet to encounter an issue with it.

Comment: The only sources I can find for this are borderline clickbait reddit posts proclaiming (effectively) "set this magic bit to cure all your gaming woes!" with no real information. Have you found any authoritative sources on this or are you hoping that this is what we will provide?

Comment: Well im hoping this is what you will provide.

I realise it does sound like some dumb clickbait but it really did make a big difference for me.

I dont know where else to look for info

Comment: I wasn't meaning to imply your question was clickbait, only that a cursory glance on the internet found only that style of "try this and you'll never go back" claims with little information on *why* it helps nor even a real explanation of what problem it is actually solving. Presumably it is doing *something* as there are people who seem to claim it it like night and day but I agree it would be good to know why. My interest is definitely piqued here. I've not knowingly seen microstuttering, perhaps I am too old and my eyesight too bad, but I'm curious what this setting is and what it fixes.

Comment: yeah, its not so much microstutter as it is a slight delay between when you move the mouse and when your camera in game moves.
Its one of those things that you never notice until you change it and suddenly it just feels sharper, more crisp and smooth, and if you try to go back you wonder how you could ever have played like that haha

Comment: Looking into it all I can find is more of the same. I suspect that the real information on what each setting actually does is hidden behind an some kind of Developer NDA/SDK combo which allows you to submit preferred game settings for inclusion into the game profiles in the Nvidia console. It's odd just how little *real* information there is for these settings.